# how do i preserve item selected from spinner even after exiting app?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

Here is my code below, which is getting item from spinner on click

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

private Spinner spinner1,spinner2,spinner3;
private static final String[] sports = {
        "Hockey","Cricket","Football","Basketball","Badminton","Tennis"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner);

    spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.drop_down);
    spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.drop_down2);
    spinner3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.drop_down3);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,sports);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner3.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
}
}
```

How do I preserve the selected spinners' item even after exiting the application?

Comment: Use `SharedPreference`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreference`  to store the selected value position/id/string.

Simply add this line when you get String item

```
Editor edit = context.getSharedPreferences("Name_of_sf",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
edit.putString("selected_item", item);
edit.commit();
```

And can simply retrieve the value as

```
context.getSharedPreferences("Name_of_sf",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("selected_item", "");
```

Comment: how can i use sharedpreferneces in it?

Answer (score 0):

For more info @AnirudhSohil you could see the official documentation, it has a very detail examples, I hope that it helps you.

[image]
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html